# How many players have been out on 99 run in their international cricket match debut?

Tags: cricket, statistics

Many players have been out on 99 over the years in international cricket match but the question is how many of those player became out in their debut match?

This [Link of crickinfo](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/94500.html) shows many batsman who were dismissed for 99 in test.

So what is total number of player who got out in 99 at their debut game combining test, ODI, t20i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asim Kamal (PAK) '03
AG Chipperfield (AUS) '34
RJ Christiani (WI) '48
EJG Morgan (IRE) '06
SP Patil* (UAE) '14

All were dismissed at 99 in their debut. SP Patil was not out. Hope this helps!

http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=11;debut_or_last=1;filter=advanced;orderby=runs;runsmax1=99;runsmin1=99;runsval1=runs;template=results;type=batting